# How to set the start screen in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone

I developed an app which takes 2-3 seconds to start up. I want to show a picture in this time frame, a UIImage or some other view.  How can I do that?  I tried pasting it in the window but it isnt showing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add an image to your project called Default.png. This is what the iPhone will show while your application is launching.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to accomlish this is as follow:
1. Start XCode
2. From Xcode run the app on the iPhone and have it show excast screen you need
3. in XCode start Organiser tool

Organiser tool will allow you to capture screen directly from the connected iPhone and will even give you an option to have this saved as default.png directly as part of your project.

Worked great for me